# Folder structure to nested HTML list

Tags: php, html, directory

I have a complex folder structure, with folders inside folders etc.. and I want to display the structure in a html nested list.

I want to use PHP to look at the folders and then display there names. How do i do this, or has it been done before?

Comment: http://us3.php.net/readdir use `readdir` and a recursive function to traverse through all of your directories

Answer (score 2):

Use [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php). Something like this:

```
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/directory');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir) as $filename => $file) {
    if($file->isDir())
        echo $filename . '<br/>';
}
```